# How to enter data from the keyboard

Tags: c#

I need to enter the values of the array from the keyboard

I have this task: **Write a program to check if the first element and the last element are equal of an array of integers and the length is 1 or more.**

Test Data:
`Array1: [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1]`

Sample Output
`True`

I also have a code with a fixed data input

```cs
int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 1 }; 

Console.WriteLine((numbers.Length >= 1) && (numbers[0].Equals(numbers[numbers.Length - 1])));
```

I also have attempts to solve this problem

```cs
int[] arr = new int[100];
int i, num = 0;

Console.WriteLine("Write size of array: ");
num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
Console.WriteLine("Write " + num + " elements in the array: ");

for (i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}

Console.WriteLine((arr.Length >= num) && (arr[0].Equals(arr[arr.Length - num])));
```

But it does not work, I would like to get help from you, thank you in advance.

Comment: "But it does not work". _What_ doesn't work?

Comment: your first attempt work correctly

Comment: In the first version, the executable values are written into the code, but I need these values to be entered by the user himself, using the keypad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example works right with elements comparation and you have to fix just 2 things in your second example.

You're creating an array of size 100, which is unnecessary since the user will be inputting the size of the array. You can remove this line:

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
```

and change it to next one after reading array size from console:

```
var arr = new int[num];
```

Also you should be checking if the number of elements entered by the user is greater than or equal to 1 and if the first element `[0]` is equal to the last element `[Length - 1]`.

```
using System;

public class Exercise16
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Write size of array: ");
        var num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        var arr = new int[num];

        Console.WriteLine("Write " + num + " elements in the array: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
        {
            arr[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        }

        Console.WriteLine(num >= 1 && arr[0] == arr[num - 1]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because you defined the array to be of size 100 before you ask the user what size the array should be i.e.

```
int[] arr = new int[100];
```

You should define the array after you know what size it should be:

```
Console.WriteLine("Write size of array: ");

num = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

int[] arr = new int[num];

Console.WriteLine("Write " + num + " elements in the array: ");
```